# sed substitution with user-specified replacement string

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

The general form of the [substitution command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command) in [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Top) is:

```
s/regexp/replacement/flags
```

where the '/' characters may be uniformly replaced by any other single character. But how do you choose this separator character when the replacement string is being fed in by an environment variable and might contain any printable character? Is there a straightforward way to escape the separator character in the variable using `bash`?

The values are coming from trusted administrators so security is not my main concern. (In other words, please don't answer with: "Never do this!") Nevertheless, I can't predict what characters will need to appear in the replacement string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use control character as regex delimiters also like this:

```
s^Aregexp^Areplacement^Ag
```

Where `^A` is <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> pressed together.

Or else use `awk` and don't worry about delimiters:

```
awk -v s="search" -v r="replacement" '{gsub(s, r)} 1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Here isn't (easy) solution for the following using the `sed`.

```
while read -r string from to wanted
do
    echo "in [$string] want replace [$from] to [$to]  wanted result: [$wanted]"
    final=$(echo "$string" | sed "s/$from/$to/")
    [[ "$final" == "$wanted" ]] && echo OK || echo WRONG
    echo
done <<EOF
=xxx= xxx === =====
=abc= abc /// =///=
=///= /// abc =abc=
EOF
```

what prints

```
in [=xxx=] want replace [xxx] to [===]  wanted result: [=====]
OK

in [=abc=] want replace [abc] to [///]  wanted result: [=///=]
sed: 1: "s/abc/////": bad flag in substitute command: '/'
WRONG

in [=///=] want replace [///] to [abc]  wanted result: [=abc=]
sed: 1: "s/////abc/": bad flag in substitute command: '/'
WRONG
```

Can't resists: *Never do this!* (with sed). :)

> Is there a straightforward way to escape the separator character in
>   the variable using bash?

No, because you passing the strings from variables, you can't easily escape the separator character, because in `"s/$from/$to/"` the separator  can appear not only in the `$to` part but in the `$from` part too. E.g. when you escape the separator it in the `$from` part it will not do the replacement at all, because will not find the `$from`.

Solution: use something other as `sed`

1.) Using pure bash. In the above script instead of the `sed` use the

```
    final=${string//$from/$to}
```

2.) If the bash's substitutions are not enough, use something to what you can pass the `$from` and `$to` as variables.

- as @anubhava already said, can use: `awk -v f="$from" -v t="$to" '{gsub(f, t)} 1' file`
- or you can use `perl` and passing values as environment variables

```
final=$(echo "$string" | perl_from="$from" perl_to="$to" perl -pe 's/$ENV{perl_from}/$ENV{perl_to}/')
```

- or passing the variables to perl via the command line arguments

```
final=$(echo "$string" | perl -spe 's/$f/$t/' -- -f="$from" -t="$to")
```

Answer (score 0):

2 options:

1) take a char not in the string (need a pre process on content check and possible char without warranty that a char is available)

```
# Quick and dirty sample using `'/_#@|!%=:;,-` arbitrary sequence

Separator="$( printf "%sa%s%s" '/_#@|!%=:;,-' "${regexp}" "${replacement}" \
 | sed -n ':cycle
     s/\(.\)\(.*a.*\1.*\)\1/\1\2/g;t cycle
     s/\(.\)\(.*a.*\)\1/\2/g;t cycle
     s/^\(.\).*a.*/\1/p
    ' )"
echo "Separator: [ ${Separator} ]"
sed "s${Separator}${regexp}${Separator}${replacement}${Separator}flag" YourFile
```

2) escape the wanted char in the string patterns (need a pre process to escape char).

```
# Quick and dirty sample using # arbitrary with few escape security check
regexpEsc="$( printf "%s" "${regexp}" | sed 's/#/\\#/g' )"
replacementEsc"$( printf "%s" "${replacement}" | sed 's/#/\\#/g' )"
sed 's#regexpEsc#replacementEsc#flags' YourFile
```

Answer (score 0):

From `man sed`

> ```
> \cregexpc  
>           Match lines matching the regular expression regexp.  The  c  may  be  any
>           character.
> ```

When working with paths i often use `#` as separator:

```
sed s\#find/path#replace/path#
```

No need to escape `/` with ugly `\/`.